# Spring Cache - Only cache some tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I want to cache some database tables in my application since the content in the tables are only updated once per day.

I got Spring Cache to work like this:

```
@Service("stuffManager")
public class StuffManagerImpl implements StuffManager {

    @Autowired
    private StuffDao stuffDao;

    @Override
    @Cacheable("stuffCache")
    public List<Stuff> getAllStuff() {
        return stuffDao.getAllStuff();
    }
}
```

```
@Repository("stuffDao")
public class StuffDaoHibernate implements StuffDao {

    @Override
    public List<Stuff> getAllStuff() {
        return getHQLResult("select* from Stuff", null);
    }
}
```

But is it possible to use Spring Cache if my `getAllStuff`-method looked like this but I only wanted to cache the `Stuff`-table?

```
@Repository("stuffDao")
public class StuffDaoHibernate implements StuffDao {

    @Override
    public List<Stuff> getAllStuff() {
        return getHQLResult("select Stuff.* from Stuff inner join OtherStuff on Stuff.Id = OtherStuff.Id", null);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.Your method annotated with @Cacheable annotation is supposed to have method args, so that you can retrieve next time with arg value as the key  2. Spring cache provides abstraction to storing java object in the underlying cache. It is upto you, how you populate your java object.

Comment: @AmitParashar Could you please clarify how this could solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. Spring caches the "method execution" - when you call the method Spring checks if the key is present in the cache and returns the corresponding value else the method is called, the data is pulled from the database, added to the cache and returned. When you join some table with other table, that happens in the database.

You can't cache tables in the database with Spring Cache. Only values returned from methods.

If you want to cache some database tables in memory, some databases provide such functionality, but you have to do that in the DB, not on the server.